# iTunes hangs windows 8 on shutdown or restart

Tags: windows-8, itunes, shutdown

I have a computer that I have have put a clean install of Windows 8.1 on and everything seemed fine until I installed iTunes. At that point the computer will no longer do a clean shutdown or restart. At this point after I do a shutdown or restart it appears to do it, but it just "hangs" on a black screen and I have to power it off and back on to get it to restart. I have left it alone for up to 15-20 minutes to see if it would do it on it's own eventually, but it did not in that time frame.

Even with the power off/on Windows does not complain about the power cycle. That is, the "hang" appears to be late enough in the cycle that when Windows returns I **do not** get the message that Windows did not appear to shutdown correctly and offer up safe mode.

Things to note:

- If I uninstall iTunes, shutdown/restart is normal again. If I re-install iTunes, the problem returns.
- I have full admin rights
- I am running Windows 8.1 - 64-bit
- I am downloading iTunes 11.4 - 64-bit (current version)
- It does not make a difference if I actually run iTunes or not, which makes me think it is with an installed driver or something. I also tried manually stopping the Apple Mobile Device Windows Service first and that also did not make a difference.
- I have tried disabling Hybrid Shutdown and it makes no difference either way.

Does anyone know how to fix or at least how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be [other users](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6516134) affected by this problem too.

Try this as a check:

Before you shut down, check **Task Manager** to see if there is are any iTunes related processes running. If there are any running, end them **then** shut down.

If the shutdown occurs normally, then it is the iTunes process preventing Windows from shutting down. However normally Windows would tell you that instead of presenting you with a black screen.

If it is indeed that problem, then:
Go to the **Startup** tab in Task Manager and disable iTunes/related if present once rebooted and do the same above again. Shutdowns after this should be normal.

Note:

> I have had issues with Apple software in the past where I attempt to disable it from launching automatically when I boot the computer and it will simply create another entry for itself in the startup list.

Unfortunately that's all the advice I can give *for now*. :)

Comment: After a bunch of iterations (but not all iterations), I have determined that for me, it is the "QuickTime Task". I have disabled it from starting up and I can now reboot/shutdown properly. So there appears to be some interaction between QuickTime and iTunes, because, as I mentioned, if I uninstalled iTunes, it also worked fine. At this point I have iTunesHelper, iCloud, and iCould Photos running.